# Allow flutter web to run inside another app's iframe?

Tags: flutter, iframe, hosting

I have a two web apps, one is a next/react app hosted on vercel, the other is a flutter web app hosted on firebase.

I have embedded the flutter web app as an iframe inside the next app and it works fine in production since the hosted domains are the same. However, firebase hosting preview environments do not allow custom domains so the preview URL does not work in the iframe for my next/react app's staging environment.

How can I get around this? How can I run a firebase hosting preview URL flutter web app inside of an iframe for my other app?

Edit: More context, the flutter app loads, but I don't see any calls being made to firebase to load any data so it's just the app skeleton with the loading spinner